# How to manipulate the state in ReactRedux in realtime

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Say I get populate the state from an `fetch(api)` call. So following is my reducer:

`state.results.data` :

```
[
  1: {
     id: '1',
     name: 'name1',
     number: 11
    },
  2: {
     id: '2',
     name: 'name2',
     number: 22
    },
  3: {
     id: '3',
     name: 'name3',
     number: 33
    }   
]
```

And I show this in a `ListView` by a `map` function. I have a TouchableOpacity for `onPress` `number = number+1`. This I do by `dispatch` an `action` to the reducer. Like a `like` button. So the value for say `2` is now :

```
2: {
     id: '2',
     name: 'name2',
     number: 23       // <= number increased onPress.
    }
```

I am able to do this. The number updates realtime in the view. But how do I do this on the database. Say I have MySQL in the backened and passing queries through `node`. I think I need to do a `dispatch` to `action` to increase the value of `number` for `id=2` and send this call to the `api` through `fetch` `post`. Now this will take some time. Like a second or 2 and the actual data in db is different that the one already in the state. How do I show the updated information for `id:2` or what is a preferred way to go about this?

Hope I explained it. Ready to answer any questions for clarification.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a middle-ware like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).
This will let you dispatch a `function` as opposed to what you normally should do which is dispatch an `Object`.
Now if you can dispatch a `function` that function can `fetch` and maybe even return a `promise`. When that promise is resolved you can dispatch the action creator like you normally doing.
For example:

```
// someActions.js
export function updateSomething(id) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: 'FETCH_IN_PROGRESS'});
        fetch(`myServer.com/updateSomething?id=${id}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((item) => dispatch({type: "SOMETHING_UPDATED", id}))
    };
}
```

Note that i didn't include error handling which i strongly recommend to do (like `.catch`).

When you create your store you should inject this middle-ware:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

    // Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
```

Comment: `.then((item) => dispatch({type: "SOMETHING_UPDATED", id}))` is there where I update the existing state? I'm using `redux-thunk`.

Comment: Yeah, a relevant `reducer` should catch this action and return the new state

Comment: You mean only that object of the state should be returned with this logic right? And not the entire state. Testing the code.

Comment: @Somename your reducer can handle a portion of the state or the whole state it's up to you, how you structure them . and about actions and reducers, it's not one-to-one relationship, a reducer can handle one or more action types, and one action type can be handled in one or multiple reducers or none at all.

Comment: Your logic works! I am able to `push` some dummy data in the `data` array from an action to api. Now will work on updating the existing data. One last question. I know you explained it but I'm a little confused. So can I dispatch an action and have multiple reducers listen to it and update the state at the same time?

Comment: @Somename yeah, this pattern is named _reducer composition_ you can read about it [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#splitting-reducers)